# org.apache.log4j not able to identify my log4j.properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I have been trying to use log4j(or for that matter, any kind of logging library) for the first time. I am not able to make it work after almost 2 days of efforts.

Here is the log4j.properties file that I am using but it seems that the logger (called from within a junit test suite class) does not use this file at all.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(myclass.class.getName());
...
logger.error("Message");
...
```

It simply types out the messages at the console(file is not created) and when I remove the appender X  from rootLogger, it still spits the messages at console.

This file is kept under a package named: "resources" under the project directory in Eclipse. I have three other source packages from where I will like to use this configuration file, that's why I have made a separate package for this file.

Is it a file creation permission issue, or the parameters case is wrong(given java is strongly typed), or the location of this file?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, X, RUNLOG

log4j.appender.X=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.X.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.X.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n

log4j.appender.RUNLOG=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.RUNLOG.file=run.log
log4j.appender.RUNLOG.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.RUNLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RUNLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the output of your program when started with `-Dlog4j.debug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Log4J expects to find its configuration file in the "default package": it simply looks up a resource called `log4j.properties` (and later `log4j.xml`, but that's another story) and expects it to be found in the classpath.

You mentioned that your Log4J configuration file is inside a package called `resources`, which is exactly why it can't find it.

You have the following options:

- Move the `log4j.properties` file so it's located in the default package.
- Create a folder in your project (*not* a package), place your `log4j.properties` file there and add that folder to your runtime classpath.
- Specify the `log4j.configuration` system property, providing it with the path to the Log4J configuration file.

Comment: Thanks people, the problem was some beta package that I had downloaded from one of the mirrors.It had unusually large number of jar files. The correct package was at apache log4j archives site. I have to do more stuff with Logger and hope that it will go smooth now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `resources` folder is in your classpath. Try adding the folder to your classpath using `Project->Properties->Java Build ->Libraries ->Add Class Folder`